# Kiuj reformoj plifaciligus Esperanton al azianoj?

Tags: grammar

Specife al ĉinoj kaj japanoj. Mi antaŭe aŭdis ke Esperanto ne tiom facilas al ili.

Comment: Mi vidas ke iu donis minuson al tiu demando. Cxu estas bona kialo por fermi gxin? Laux mia kompreno tiu retejo estas por demandoj pri Esperanto, ne pri reformoj. Se tiu ja estas bona demando por tiu retjo, mi dubas cxu la etikedo "grammar" tauxgas.

Comment: Mi konsentas pri tiu lasta frazo, sed mi dirus ke ankaŭ demandoj pri reformoj (ĉar temas pri *esperantaj* reformoj) taŭgas por esperanta Stack Exchange. Povas esti, ke mi malpravas, sed laŭ mi estus bone kunigi kiel eble plej multe da informoj pri diversaj aspektoj de/aferoj rilataj al la lingvo.

Comment: Mi pensas ke demandoj pri reforomoj estas tre taugxaj. Aldonas diversecon al nia demandaro.

Answer (score 2):

Mi provos respondi, eĉ se mi ne estas aziano. :-) Mi pensas ke la plej granda problemo por orientazianoj – ja ankaŭ multaj ekz-e Rusoj loĝas en Azio – ne estas la gramatiko, sed la latinid-greka vortostoko de Esperanto. Plejparto de Eŭropaj lingvoj havas ekz-e la vorton ”demokratio”, dum en orientaziaj lingvoj oni emas ne preni grek-latinan radikon, sed mem konstrui el naciaj elementoj (do ’popol-rego’ por demokratio). Do, precipe ĉinlingvano devas parkerigi multege da vortoj kiujn jam konas Franco aŭ Germano. Krome, mi laŭ propra sperto scias ke povas malfacili analizi Esperantajn kunmetaĵojn kaj distingi ilin disde nekunmetaĵoj. Iama koramikino mia Orientazia tute ne komprenis la vorton ”necesejpapero” – ĉar ĉu temas pri ”ne-”, pri ”-ero”, ks., kaj kio estas ”necesa ejo”? Tio verŝajne kulturdependas, kaj ne ĉiu homo de la tero unue pensus pri la loko por meti siajn ekskrementon kaj urinon, kiel Eŭropano. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Probable vi volas diri [Norma ĉina lingvo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norma_%C4%89ina_lingvo), ĉar "ĉinoj" kunigas tro da  lingvaj grupoj.

Japanoj estas tute alia, laŭ miaj konoj.

Nu, por respondi pli vaste al la demando pri aziaj lingvanoj, vi probable ŝatos legi "Esperanto: ĉu eŭropa aŭ azia lingvo?" (retumebla Angla versio: [Esperanto: european or asiatic language?](http://claudepiron.free.fr/articlesenanglais/europeanorasiatic.htm) fare de [Claude Piron](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Piron)).

Answer (score 1):

Laŭ mi, iom da la plej bonaj esperantistoj estas el ĉinio.

Mi ne ŝatas reformojn, sed se vi volas, forigu la vorton '*la*' kaj uzu bildojn por skribi vortojn.